# Настройка языковой панели windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Ситуация: на языковой панеле win, стоит 5 языков которые нужны для работы (en,ru,ua,de,fr) в остальное же время используется только 2 (en,ru) и рабочие языки довольно таки мешают.

Есть ли какой-то способ, что бы скрыть их переключение через комбинацию alt+shift, а вызывать только отдельными командами, либо же добавлять и убирать их с панели каким-то макросом во время работы?

P. S. Стандартные сочетания клавиш для отдельных языков (в настройках языковой панели) по какой-то причине просто не работают, их использование неактуально.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение через создание скрипта power shell на сайте: [http://www.outsidethebox.ms/20484/](https://www.outsidethebox.ms/20484/)